# laravel-scout-elasticsearch not connecting

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

I am using `matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch` package.
I have an ElasticSearchServiceProvider in my app/Providers directory.

The client build is made as follow:

```php
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->setHosts([ 'http://'.env('ELASTICSEARCH_HOST').':'.env('ELASTICSEARCH_PORT') ])
    ->setBasicAuthentication(env('ELASTICSEARCH_USER'), env('ELASTICSEARCH_PASS'))
    ->build();
```

If I add the following code to my provider:

```php
$response = $client->info();

dd($response->getStatusCode());
```

I get `200`, so I think the elascticSearch server is totally OK.

But when I use `php artisan scout:import "App\Models\MyModel"` in my console, I have the following error:

```
In SimpleNodePool.php line 77:
  No alive nodes. All the 1 nodes seem to be down.
```

Do you know why? Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help.